# PPTP VPN client auto startup : need to restart network interface

Tags: debian, startup, vpn, pptp

The PPTP client works well.

So the following lines were added in /etc/network/interfaces to enable the tunnel at system startup :

```
auto tunnel
iface tunnel inet ppp
    provider myTunnel
```

according to [HowTo Debian : PPTP Client](http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/howto-debian.phtml)

but the vpn remain unreachable until I restart the network with :

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Did I miss anything ?

Comment: Same problem detected on Ubuntu v16.04 LTS. PPTP working by issuing `pon myTunnel`, but not on restarts.

Comment: Please post output from `sudo tail -n 1000 /var/log/syslog | grep "ppp" -i`.